# Issue when deploying WAR to live server (Springboot+Thymeleaf/CentOs)

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, centos

I am trying to deploy a simple web application to my centOs server (Digital Ocean). Followed their guide and i've managed to setup tomcat, managed to log in to manager and then deployed my war. Tomcat deployed it, it says OK without any errors in the log. But when i click on the app link it just shows 
HTTP Status 404 not found..

Tested on my local tomcat server, same procedure, works just fine.

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SuperiorniatletaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    //JAR
    /*
     * public static void main(String[] args) {
     * SpringApplication.run(SuperiorniatletaApplication.class, args); }
     */


    //WAR

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SuperiorniatletaApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SuperiorniatletaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
....
<packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>superiorniatleta</name>
    <description>Get strong</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MARIADB CONNECTOR -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <!-- USED FOR LIVE WITH SCOPE WAR -->
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>   

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
         <finalName>Superiorni-Atleta</finalName>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/atleta_db
spring.datasource.username=atleta_admin
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.datasource.driverclassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=20000KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=20000KB


# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, active from user where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?
```

Checked MariaDb, its on that local port 3306, tried to log in with atleta_admin credentials, works fine...I can not seem to find the issue, i figure it has something to do with CentOs itself? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

**Tried changing file permission in tomcat itself with no success, also tried uploading my previous project which has worked on another droplet with same result..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that newer versions of tomcat restrict connection from the server itself. Had to go into 
/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
and delete

```
<!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
```

inside of context. Hope this helps someone!